# printf char type in base16 with confused phenomenon

Tags: c, printf

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(unsigned char v)
{
    char c = v;
    unsigned char uc = v;
    printf("%%X: %X, %X\n", c, uc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f(0x80);   
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
%X: FFFFFF80, 80
```

I'm confused. How `FFFFFF80` come. We know that `char` type holds 1 byte. And I know that the difference between `char` and `unsigned char` is the way they treating highest bit , but both holds one byte. 
And I don't think this program concerning any conversion process. 
The sign bit will expand if type of `c` is `int` (convert unsigned char to int).But in this case, it's `unsigned char` converting to `char`, **but both holds one byte**.

So why the result of `printf("%X",c)` contain 4 bytes?

Comment: Smaller than int data types are promoted to int when passed as arguments. And char 0x80 is actually -128.

Comment: @RustyX But whatever, `c` won't holds 4 bytes right?

Comment: @RustyX Try to avoid answering in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function, it is defined as:

```
int printf(const char * fmt, ...);
```

That is, `printf` does not know the types of arguments you passed to it, it relies on the format string to deduce the argument types.

Every argument after the format string is subject to integer promotions (`char` is promoted to `int`).

So what `printf` receives in your case is a format string (`"%%X: %X, %X\n"`), an `int` containing `-128` (because `0x80` represented as a `char` on two's-complement architecture is `-128`) and an `int` containing `128`.

References:

ISO C § 6.3.1.1:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value
>   is converted to an `int`; otherwise,   it   is   converted   to   an
>   `unsigned int`.   These   are   called   the ***integer promotions***.

ISO C § 6.5.2.2:

> If  the  expression  that  denotes  the  called  function  has  a 
>   type  that  does  not  include  a prototype,  the  ***integer 
>   promotions***  are  performed  on  each  argument,  and  arguments  that
>   have  type `float` are  promoted  to `double`.  These  are  called 
>   the ***default  argument promotions***.
>
> The  ellipsis  notation  in  a  function  prototype  declarator 
>   causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared
>   parameter.  The ***default argument promotions*** are performed on
>   trailing arguments.

---

P.S.
It is worth noting that the two's complement behavior you're experiencing is *implementation-defined*, i.e. `(char)0x80` is not guaranteed to equal `-128` on all platforms.

Comment: "char is promoted to int, unsigned char to unsigned int" <- `unsigned char` should also be promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, the answer is *integer promotion*, which is indeed a bit harder to understand:

#### 1. what is it:

*integer promotion* means that integer types smaller than `int` are automatically converted to `int` **if** `int` can hold all values of the original integer type (obviously the case for `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`) -- otherwise they're converted to `unsigned int`.

#### 2. when does it happen:

*integer promotion* happens basically in two situations.

1) in arithmetic expressions:

```
signed char x = 40;
signed char y = 100;
unsigned char z = x + y; // <-- here, the addition is done with two ints
```

2) in function arguments if the argument is a variadic argument (like when calling `printf`) or if the function doesn't have a prototype, IOW, **if the argument type is not known**.

```
char x = 'A';
printf("value: %d\n", x); // <-- here, x is passed as an int
```

---

So, the answer to your question is: for a `signed char`, `0x80` is the representation of `-128`. `-128` as an `int` is represented as `0xffffff80`.